# CRUD FLS issue to edit task access for site guest user

Tags: apex, apexrest, fls, crud, restresource

I am applying CRUD FLS on task object fields and also I have provided read and edit access to task for site user profile. Even checked with sharing settings as 'Controlled by parent'.

But still when I debug that field is accessible but not having updateable access so it's not entering inside if loop. Below is the code for reference

```
for (Task objTask : taskList){
     if(Schema.SObjectType.Task.fields.Message_Status__c.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.Task.fields.Message_Status__c.isUpdateable()){              
            objTask.Message_Status__c = taskStatus;
     }
}
```

Comment: Might be related to this known issue. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008djFAAQ

Comment: Are these tasks related to a specific object? Site.com Users don't have any CRUD access to Accounts or Contacts. The Site.com Guest User profile by default has R,C CRUD on standard objects (except Account & Contact, plus children) & full CRUD on up to 25 custom objects. So if a task is related to an Account, Contact, or Opportunity, you're not going to be able to update it.

Comment: You could always use apex to represent the object, allowing the site guest user to read, update, etc via the sudo object

Answer (score 0):

How were you able to add CRUD for the task object in the site user? that object is not in the options (only the fields), but like @crmprogdev you are not going to be able to do this, even is you set everything to public.

I had this before, the only alternative sadly for sites, was having a custom object to replace this task.

perhaps a trigger will do the trick when a native task is edited, created, deleted, undeleted .... ammend the custom activity object

and i will add a trigger in the custom object to update the task that is link to make sure the class of this trigger is without sharing

```
public without sharing class
```

if this doesnt update the actual task, you might need to set a schedule job, this way the job is excecuted by a user with the full task permissions

Just an idea

Sharing settings of activity
[image]

Comment: Yes that can be happen. So it means that we cannot apply updateable FLS access on task for site guest users?

Comment: @Vinod perhaps i need to clarify, site license is quite limited, what is the parent object of the task/event?

Comment: It is contact. That I need to apply FLS for appExchange.